# Can't understand an odd Python lambda function

Tags: python, function, lambda

I'm going through Edabit to brush up on my Python. I particularly love looking through other people's solutions to see all their creative solutions, and hopefully learn something new myself.

The challenge was to write a function that converts hours into seconds (not very complicated, I know). I took a look through some other solutions and saw basically what I expected: some shortened snippets, some lambda functions... nothing too difficult.

I scrolled down to see the following code: `seconds = 3600..__mul__`

It looks similar to a lamda function, but I'm not sure. I'm semi-aware of how the standard operators work, but the double dot especially confused me.

Can someone give me an explanation of how that line of code works? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it's a lambda function? There's no `lambda` keyword.

Comment: It's a bound class method.

Comment: Note, you **definitely shouldn't use this**. Don't use `__dunder__` methods directly.

Answer (score 1):

`3600..__mul__` can be more readably written as `(3600.).__mul__`, where `3600.` is a float literal, and the following `.` gets an attribute from the preceding object by the name that follows, and `__mul__` is a built-in dunder method that implements the multiplication operation for the object it's bound to.

In other words, `3600..__mul__` returns a bound method that performs multiplication with the floating number of `3600.`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a lambda function, it's a bound class method.

When you write an expression like

```
x * y
```

it's processed internally as a call to the `__mul__` method of `x`, i.e.

```
x.__mul__(y)
```

`x.__mul__` is the class's `__mul__()` method with its `self` argument bound to the value of `x`.

But it doesn't have to be a variable. If you write

```
3600. * y
```

it's equivalent to

```
3600..__mul__(y)
```

(the extra `.` is needed because the first `.` in a number is treated a decimal point, we need another one to be the attribute operator).

So from that you can see that `3600..__mul__` is a function that multiplies its argument by `3600.`. It's approximately equivalent to the lambda function:

```
seconds = lambda y: 3600. * y
```

If you want to multiply by an integer `3600` instead of the float `3600.` you can use parentheses, because a `.` by itself is a decimal point.

```
seconds = (3600).__mul__
```

But that's one more character and I guess the person who wrote the code was being judged by character count (as in Code Golf) or just wanted to make it more confusing.

Or you could use whitespace:

```
seconds = 3600 .__mul__
```

Comment: Ah, okay. I understand it pretty well now, thanks for all the details! I've got one question though, and it may seem stupid as I'm not sure how to phrase it: how does the `__mul__` function get an input? With a lambda function (e.g. `lambda x: x + 1`), you can see that it expects `x` as an input. Is that just not visible with the `__mul__` function?

Comment: For int you don't **need** parentheses, you can do `3600 .__mul__`.

Comment: I'll bet the guy who wrote with the double dot is kicking himself for not thinking of that.

Comment: @Manuel Ah, okay. So, realistically, there was no need for it to be a float. Got it. Side question: why is `3600 .__mul__` syntactically correct, but `3600.__mul__` is not? What does the space change?

Comment: Because you can't split up parts of a float, it has to be a single token. `3600 .123` is not a valid float.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I suspect making it a float wasn't desired. Btw it's not really fully equivalent to that lambda function. For example it'll error for `y = type('', (), {'__rmul__': print})()`, whereas the lambda function will work.

Comment: @Manuel I added a qualifier.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, it's finally clicked! I misinterpreted your comment. I understand it perfectly now. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you put in parentheses it's easier to understand.

```
seconds = (3600.).__mul__ # I assume some stuff was left off this statement.
```

The key is that the two dots are parsed separately.  The first is part of the number, making it a `float` instead of an `int`.  The second is just the usual member function syntax, calling the built-in multiplication operator `__mult__`.

According to the comment, there was no function call on that statement, the stuff I assumed had been left off was actually not there.  So the variable `seconds` was bound to the `__mult__` member function of `3600.`. That's probably why it looked like a lambda, because I'll bet the next line was:

```
return seconds(hours)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! Seeing it written like that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Oh, I should also point out that the above code was the complete statement. Nothing was left off. I'm slightly confused as to where the variable for the amount of hours is used.

Comment: @MichaelO'Connell I've made an edit explaining what I think was happening then.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! Thanks for the update. That's answered a good few questions (and opened another can of worms, but nothing that a quick Google can't solve!).

Comment: I'd rather bet that the next line was... really not there. They said "The challenge was to write a function that converts hours into seconds", and presumably that function's name is supposed to be `seconds`.

Comment: @Manuel you're probably right.  I had that thought too, but not until after I wrote what I did.